# Razor C# template HTML helper?

Tags: c#, razor

I am trying to pass some other vaules to input like this in Razor C#

```
 @(Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "t-input medium field-text", @id = 'password' , @data='required'}))
```

The problem is i got syntax error?

Any idea where  did i make a mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string properties in the anonymous type instance passed as the second parameter should all be quoted using double quotes

```
@Html.PasswordFor(
    m => m.Password, 
    new { 
        @class = "t-input medium field-text", 
        id = "password", 
        data = "required" })
```

Only the `class` property need be prefixed with `@` as it is a c# reserved keyword. If you want to pass `data-` attributes or any other attributes that contain hyphens, simply use underscores in the property name in the anonymous type and these will be converted to hyphens by the helper.